# Unable to initialize a hash within a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

For some reason I cannot initialize a hash in my view.  I was able to initialize it with a simple hash (instead of a hash of hashes).

Here is model code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :categories, :name, :description
    serialize :goals, Hash


end
```

Here is the view code that fails to initialize:

```
  <% @product.categories || {"0" => {"category_name"=> nil, "effective_date"=> nil},"1" => {"category_name" => nil, "effective_date"=> nil}} %>

  <%= @product.categories %>
```

I do not get any error but the hash remains empty. The second line of code shows "{}".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% @product.categories ||= {"0" => {"category_name"=> nil, "effective_date"=> nil},"1" => {"category_name" => nil, "effective_date"=> nil}} %>
```

note that `||=` instead of `||`

Comment: Thanks Zed! I need to get some more coffee or maybe some sleep!

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually doing an assigment in your view code, just evaluating a statement.

Try (note the ***||=***, as compared to ***||*** in your code):

```
<% @product.categories ||= {"0" => {"category_name"=> nil, "effective_date"=> nil},"1" => {"category_name" => nil, "effective_date"=> nil}} %>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! I definitely needed a second pair of eyes to look at that!